# Enumerating all possible permutations when each element belongs to a set

Tags: algorithm, performance

**Problem:** You are given a natural number N and a set of elements of size M. Your task is to generate *all* possible values of a list of size N where each element belongs to set M (both with or without repetition).

**Example:** Let N = 2 and M = < 0, 1 >.

*With repetition:*      N = [0,1] or N = [1,0] or N = [0,0] or N = [1,1]

*Without repetition:*   N = [1,0] or N = [0,1]

I came up with solution (EDIT - which is wrong) for with repetition as follows.
It is in pseudocode so that it isn't biased to anyone without knowledge of the language.

```
Let I be an auxillary list of size N.
Let l denote the last value changed in I initialized as value N.
Fill I with value 1.

while l != 0
    for i = 1 to N
        N[i] = M[I[i]]

    do_something(N)

    if I[l] != M
        I[l] += 1
    elseif l == 1
        break // So that it does not become not defined in else clause
    else
        l -= 1
        I[l] += 1
```

It takes O(N^2 * M) time and O(N + M) space. If you have better one then please post it.
I was not able to come up with a good solution for without repetition case.

Comment: With repetition there are pow( M, N) lists. If you have to generate them all, then you must take at least that number of operations.

Comment: to add to @dmuir comment, without repetition case, u have to assume (m >= n), complexity is `C(m,n)*n!`. C is a binomial coefficient

Comment: @dmuir Then this means that either the algo is wrong or the analysis. Can you tell me which one is wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create permutations with replacement in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543782/how-to-create-permutations-with-replacement-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You would see that your algorithm has a problem if you had actually tried it on some very simple cases, like for example *the one you actually gave as an example*, with M=N=2.  (Why didn't you do this first?)  It will not generate the list `1 0`.

Why?  Because after decrementing `l` and incrementing the new `I[l]`, you never decrease any of the later (further to the right) values in `I[]`.  So e.g. for N=5 you would generate only the permutations

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Yeah I noted that after commenting dmuir. I have now edited answer so that it clears any confusion. So my approach is unsuccessful. Can you suggest a right method to do it ?

Comment: The fix is pretty easy.  But this question has been answered many times on SO (see e.g. the second result of googling "enumerate permutations with repetition").